# ¿Qué género tienen los extranjerismos?

Tags: género, extranjerismos

Me he encontrado con el anglicismo "babymoon" y me ha surgido la duda: ¿Debo decir "**el babymoon**" o "**la babymoon**"?

Y más en general, ¿cómo se determina el género de los [extranjerismos](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extranjerismo)? Por ejemplo: ¿por qué decimos "**el software**" y no "**la software**", o "**la buchaca**" y no "**el buchaca**" ([catalanismo](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalanismo_%28pr%C3%A9stamo%29) - aquí tal vez porque "butxaca" es femenino en catalán).

He encontrado un interesante artículo en la web de la Real Academia Española: [Tratamiento de los extranjerismos](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/que-contiene/tratamiento-de-los-extranjerismos). Sin embargo, no menciona regla alguna sobre el género que debe usarse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contacté con la RAE a través de su espléndida sección "[Español al día](http://www.rae.es/consultas-linguisticas/departamento-de-espanol-al-dia)" y he aquí lo que respondieron. No cito textualmente, pues solamente se me autoriza a utilizar parte del contenido de su respuesta:

> En español, cuando se introduce un sustantivo extranjero de referente
>   inanimado, para el que nuestra lengua no cuenta con una traducción
>   adecuada y en cuya lengua de origen el género no se manifiesta a
>   través de la morfología, la asignación del género se ve condicionada
>   fundamentalmente por dos aspectos:
>
> 1. Su adaptación a la fonología española, en particular, de sus segmentos finales. Según este criterio, grosso modo, tomarían el
>      género femenino las voces terminadas en -a (como la lasaña, la
>      secuoya); el masculino, las terminadas en -o (el risotto); mientras
>      que, en el resto de los casos, como en los sustantivos terminados en
>      -e o en consonante, la asignación de género fluctuaría.
> 2. La adscripción a una determinada clase léxica. Así, los géneros musicales suelen ser masculinos (jazz, blues, soul, reggae, etc.), al
>      igual que los deportes o los licores. A veces la asginación genérica
>      depende del hiperónimo que se sobreentienda; así el cabernet sauvignon
>      es un vino, mientras que la cabernet sauvignon es una variedad de uva.
>
>    No existe, sin embargo, ninguna regla fija o infalible a este respecto.

Sobre el hecho de que si la lengua original del extranjerismo tiene noción de género, indican que el género en castellano puede chocar con el criterio que se basa en usar la forma en que termina la palabra.

Finalmente mencionan que, en ocasiones, el género puede venir dado del nombre elidido: «la Bauhaus» -donde se sobreentiende la escuela Bauhaus- o «el Bauhaus».

---

Desde aquí, animo a esta sección de la RAE a vincularse a este foro para seguir enriqueciendo el conocimiento del castellano y su correcto uso.

Answer (score 9):

Dependiendo de la terminación de la palabra, se le atribuye un género masculino, femenino, neutro o ambos géneros.

Un `DJ (Disk jockey)` puede ser `el DJ` así como `la DJ`. En la misma línea de ejemplo `tester, developer, wedding planner`, son profesiones de hombres y mujeres, y se les llama por igual a ambos con su respectivo artículo que los distinga: `La tester de la oficina se casa con el developer, y contrataron una wedding planner que es maravillosa`.

Como bien dices, al `software` se le atribuye el género masculino por terminar en **e**. Ya que es algo abstracto, recurrimos al artículo que suena más natural. En casos que el extranjerismo se refiera a un objeto concreto, el artículo suele hacer referencia al nombre en español a pesar de que se use la palabra extranjera: `El (teléfono/móvil) smartphone, el (disco) CD, la (computadora) PC, la (red de interntet) web, el (sitio) website, la (reunión) daily meeting, la (tableta) tablet`. Algunas veces esta regla no suena muy bien al oido, como ser `El cover (cubierta musical)` debería ser **la** pero claramente **la cover** no suena muy elegante. `La selfie` en cambio, podría ser **el selfie** pero nuevamente esa articulación tiene un sonido chocante.

Justamente por ser extranjerismos no hay reglas definidas, ya que estas palabras se suelen imponer por modas, algunas incluso se instalan en el hablar diario en cuestión de pocas semanas. *En pocas palabras, las reglas las imponen quienes utilizan estas palabras y luego se tornan aceptadas por usos y costumbres.*

Comment: Muy claro y convincente. Aunque me parece que debe existir alguna explicación lingüística de por qué nos suena "chocante" o "poco elegante" decir _el selfie_.

Comment: Interesante explicación. Nótese, sin embargo, que en lenguas con género, suele usarse al traducirse. De ahí que digamos _la baguette_ y no _el baguette_, por ejemplo. Sería interesante saber cuál es la "preponderancia" a la hora de definirlo.

Comment: Curioso, yo siempre he dicho "el pan baguette". También si no digo "pan", le asigno un género másculino al "baguette".

Comment: Seguramente con estas palabras que no tienen referente español con género, mentalmente buscamos un concepto general que "enmarque" la palabra traducida. P.ej. El [pan] baguette, la [foto] selfie. Tal vez inconcientemente recordemos las palabra "pan" y "foto" para construir la frase, aunque no las pronunciemos. (Supongo esto a partir de lo que dicen @Zukki y @Keine).

Comment: Aunque estoy de acuerdo con la idea general de esta respuesta, en España no usamos el mismo género para algunos de estos anglicismos. Aquí, *PC*, *meeting* y *selfie* son masculinas. *PC* se explica porque aquí solemos decir *ordenador* en lugar de *computadora*; *meeting*, porque usamos la versión hispanizada *mitin* para referirnos a un acto público político; y *selfie* (o *selfi*), no lo sé, la verdad.

Comment: la palabra española para selfie es "autoretrato", en masculino. Aparte de que al igual que software acaba en "e"

Comment: @JesusS O también *autofoto*; de hecho, esta última es la primera recomendación de la Fundeu (http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/autofoto-alternativa-en-espanol-a-selfie/), que también indica que *selfi* es, por el momento, de género ambiguo (http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/selfi-adaptacion-al-espanol-de-selfie/). En cualquier caso, lo más importante de esta respuesta es la última frase en cursiva.