# Why is "la Gestapo" feminine?

Tags: etimología, sustantivos, género, préstamo-lingüístico

Why is the word *Gestapo* feminine? Almost all other (non-abbreviated) loanwords I can think of ending in *-o* have been absorbed as masculine. Is it because it is [associated with](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/grammatical-gender-of-loanwords.1484689/#post-16665788) *policía*?

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Qué género tienen los extranjerismos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12679/1674)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it because it is associated with **policía**?

The answer is yes [according to the DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=nNmc4LzNaD6zHPhgWc) (Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas):

> **sigla**.
>  1. Se llama sigla tanto a la palabra formada por las iniciales
>   de los términos que integran una denominación compleja, como a cada
>   una de esas letras iniciales. Las siglas se utilizan para referirse de
>   forma abreviada a organismos, instituciones, empresas, objetos,
>   sistemas, asociaciones, etc.
>   ...
>   4. Género. **Las siglas adoptan el género de la palabra que constituye el núcleo de la expresión abreviada**, que normalmente ocupa el primer
>   lugar en la denominación: el FMI, por el «Fondo» Monetario
>   Internacional; la OEA, por la «Organización» de Estados Americanos; la
>   Unesco, por la United Nations Educational, Scientific and Cultural
>   «Organization» (‘Organización de Naciones Unidas para la Educación, la
>   Ciencia y la Cultura’)

Let me try to translate the quoted text:

> 1.We apply the name **sigla** both to the word formed by the initials of the terms that combine in a complex denomination and to each of the
>   initial letters. Siglas are used to refer in an abbreviated form to
>   organizations, institutions, companies, objects, systems, associations, etc
>   ...
>   4.Gender. **Siglas adopt the gender of the word that represents the nucleus of the abbreviated expression**, that which usually occupies the first place in the term: el FMI (**Fondo** Monetario Internacional; la OEA (**Organización** de Estados Americanos), la UNESCO (United Nations Educational, Scientific and Cultural **Organization**), ...

So, it seems that Gestapo (Geheime Staatspolizei) follows this rule, its nucleus being polizei.

Thinking about this question, I've realized that there is a rare exception to this rule: **KGB** (in Spanish: Comité para la Seguridad del Estado). I've read both el KGB and la KGB. We can use **el** taking **Comité** as its nucleus but we also may use **la** because KGB is a secret **police agency**, like their counterpart la CIA. KGB was an **agency** and a sort of **police** like the Gestapo so we use **la** as determiner as well.

Comment: mmm no sé hasta qué punto la entrada del DPD aplica aquí, pues estamos hablando de una palabra extranjera.

Comment: @fedorqui Si lees atentamente, en la propia entrada del DPD se menciona UNESCO (ver arriba), cuyas siglas no han sido traducidas al español y se usa tal cual. El mismo caso que en gestapo.

Comment: Sí, lo vi, pero no sé hasta qué punto está cogiendo _organización_ del castellano, pues en inglés no hay género. Me parece algo forzado, vaya, que se vaya a la sigla original, se coja el núcleo, se mire el género y se aplique al castellano. Si fuera el caso, entonces habría que destacar que _polizei_ en alemán es femenina. Por lo que veo en http://www.wordreference.com/ende/police sí es.

Comment: No entiendo esa parte de que se vaya a la palabra del idioma original a buscar el género, que es lo que parece que apunta guifa en su respuesta. Yo creo que se refiere al género de la palabla nuclear en español. Policía en español es femenino independientemente de lo que sea en alemán. CIA no tiene género en inglés, en español le ponemos la porque es una Agencia que es femenino en español.

Comment: Sí, no acabo de ver cuál es el recorrido. Porque por ejemplo decimos _el FBI_, masculino, cuando FBI es Federal Bureau of Investigation = Oficina Federal de Investigación, ergo por ser oficina debería ser _la FBI_.

Comment: @fedorqui Buró existe en castellano y es masculino, el Buró Federal de Investigación

Comment: Creo que daría para otra pregunta, la formularé cuando tenga tiempo de investigar un poco. En cualquier caso, no creo que proceda incluirlo en la respuesta porque no tiene que ver con la pregunta original.

Comment: @fedorqui No entiendo tu reticencia a incluirlo, si no tiene que ver ¿porqué lo has mencionado? Es un ejemplo más de como se cumple la regla del DPD que he citado. Pero vamos, si quieres borro ese párrafo, sin problema.

Comment: Lo he mencionado porque me parecía un contraejemplo de lo que planteabas. Dado que puede que sea por lo de _buró_, no creo que haga falta ponerlo porque vendría a ser un ejemplo más de tu tesis. ¡Gracias!

Comment: No dije que el género viniese del de la palabra alemana, solo apunté que la palabra alemana es también femenina lo cual podría reforzar el efecto de usar la forma femenina por el género de *policía* en los idiomas romances.

Comment: @guifa Bueno, tu texto original destacaba especialmente esa coincidencia de género con la palabra alemana y no he sido el único en darle esa interpretación. Quizás no estaba tan claro.

Answer (score 32):

In all the Romance languages, *gestapo* is feminine despite its ending.  It is most likely that whichever language first imported it (probably either French or Italian) figured that because *gestapo* stands in for *Geheime Staatspolizei* (policía estatal secreta), the appropriate use would be to make it feminine as with the analogous words *la police* <sub>(FR)</sub>, *la polizia* <sub>(IT)</sub> especially considering that *polizei* is, coincidentally, also feminine in German.   Spanish and others, in turn, maintained that usage, although it's possible for separately and independently maintaining the feminine nature of *policía/polizei*.

Also, even though it ends in *-o* which normally pushes words to be masculine, I find that acronyms and abbreviations for organizations tend to maintain the connection to the base noun's gender moreso than more common nouns.

Comment: "...the appropriate use would be to make it feminine as it also is in German." - Do you mean that when borrowing the word from German, the language actually considers the article in the original language?  (As opposed to say, borrowed words always/mostly being feminine)?

Comment: @BruceWayne feminine because *policía* is feminine.  That it is also feminine in German is more of coincidental point, hence "as it also is" rather than "as it is".

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying, missed that!

Comment: *"In all the Romance languages, gestapo is feminine..."* I was taught that **all** loanwords in Italian were masculine ("il sistema" being a good example). And yet, sure enough, if I look up Gestapo in an Italian dictionary, it's feminine. All rules are meant to be broken, I guess.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder *sistema* isn't a loanword to Italian - it was inherited from Latin *systēma*, itself from Ancient Greek σύστημα (*sústēma*).

Comment: @ukemi - It was taught to me as a loanword from Greek. (This was the example my Italian teacher gave, anyway. She may have picked a poor example.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This Italian SE post might be of interest to you: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8517/gender-of-foreign-words

Comment: @ukemi - Interesting. My Italian teacher was a native Italian (and also had a master's level degree in language tuition). But anyone can make mistakes.

Comment: I suspect that the feminine gender of *Polizei* is not coincidental at all, but a consequence of the word's origin in Latin *politia.*

Comment: @Phoog absolutely, it's counnidental in the sense that the German gender of the word likely had little to no influence on the gender chosen upon reimportation within *Gestapo*

Comment: That seems likely indeed.  I was just looking into *Stasi* which is usually feminine (though sometimes masculine) in German, while the noun analogous to *Polizei* in *Gestapo* is either neuter *(Ministerium)* or masculine *(Dienst).*  It seems Spanish also treats it as feminine; could that also be because of the association with (the concept of) police even though the name does not actually contain or derive from "police"?

Comment: "Stasi" = "Staatssicherheit" in German and as the last part of compound nouns in german determines the gender ("die Sicherheit") it s female in german. Not sure which gender it has in Espanol.

Comment: Anda, ¡te cayó la medalla Populista! A ver si la medalla de oro sirve para inspiración para la tesis y te vemos pronto por aquí de nuevo. ¡Un abrazo!

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver la hipotética importación de la palabra del italiano o del francés con su género en español?  En español es también *la policía*.

Comment: @c.p. **It is most likely that whichever language first imported it (probably either French or Italian)…**  La importación de palabras dentro de lenguas hermanas suele conservar género más que la de idiomas no hermanos.

Answer (score 2):

The term "Gestapo" is a contraction of "**Ge**heime **Sta**ats**po**lizei", and the last word "Polizei", which is feminine in German, determines the grammatical gender.

Cf also the very beginning of the [Spanish Wikipedia entry for Gestapo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestapo):

> La **Gestapo** (contracción de ***Ge***heime **Sta**ats**po**lizei: 'Policía Secreta del Estado') fue la policía secreta oficial de la Alemania nazi (...)

Until the year 1936 the term "Gestapa" was also in use, a contraction of "**Ge**heimes **Sta**ats**p**olizei**a**mt", the last word being neuter in German.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this is simple - but you may not understand it fully if your native language has no specified gender for every word, such as it is in portuguese. The simple reason is that "La Gestapo" refers to "La Policia Gestapo", and "Policia" (police) is a feminine word.

There's really no specific rule for which words are masculine and which are feminine and that's why this issue may confuse those whose native language hasn't got this aspect.

Comment: As detailed in another answer, gestapo is a contraction of _Geheime Staatspolizei_ which is _German_. "-po" means police, so "La Policia Gestapo" means "the police secret state police". Maybe this is Spanish idiom, probably adopted because the "wrong" word ending sounded awful to Spanish speakers, but I am curious as to why you didn't just change the word ending: "gestapa".

Comment: But as another answer suggests there is a clear rule in Spanish for assigning the gender of abbreviations.

Comment: @PeterWone: It is a bit when we say the Sahara Desert, even though "Sahara" means "desert" ("el desierto del Sahara" it's still a common phrase in Spanish).