# How does grammatical gender work for loanwords in Spanish?

Tags: historia, género, préstamo-lingüístico, náhuatl, tagalog

Based on a hasty scan of non-Romance Spanish words in RAE’s Diccionario de la lengua española, loanword nouns that were absorbed into the language acquired a male grammatical gender. Examples include *el tequila*, *el chocolate*, *el pancit*, and *el abacá*.

Given this, how is grammatical gender applied when Spanish borrows words from languages without that concept (Nahuatl, Quecha, Tagalog, etc.)?

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Qué género tienen los extranjerismos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12679/1674)

Comment: El tequila es masculino porque es el nombre de un pueblo, "el (alcohol de) tequila". Las palabras que terminan en consonante que no sea s, n, l, d o en a tónica suelen ser masculinas.